# How to speed up awk script that uses several large gzip files?

Tags: bash, awk, files, scripting, gawk

I have two data files:

1. *file_1.in*, containing over 2k lines like *"12 AB0001"*:

   ```
   10 AB0001
   11 AC0002
   12 AD0003
   ...
   ```
2. A list of `*.gz` gzipped files (about 1 to 3 million lines) I should
   extract and parse to create one output file named as lines (second
   col) in *file_1.in*.

   ```
   ##comment..
   ##comment..
   #CHROM POS ID REF ALT QUAL FILTER INFO FORMAT AB0001 AC0002 AD0003
   21 1234567 ab11111 G A 100 PASS info1;info2 GT 0|0 0|1 0|0
   21 1234568 ab22222 C A 100 PASS info1,info2 GT 1:23:2 .:.:. 0:32:2
   21 1234569 ab33333 A C 100 PASS info1;info2 GT 0|2 1|0 0|0
   ```

Trying different approaches I came to this:

```
{
if(FNR==NR){list[$1]=$2;next}
if(!/^#/){
    for(p in list){
        split($p, sp, ":");
        if (sp[1] != "0|0" && sp[1] != "0" && sp[1] != "."){
            printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", 
            $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $p) >> out"/"list[p]".tmp"
        }
    }
} 
}
```

executed by command line:

```
awk -v out="outfolder/" -f myscript.awk file_1.in <(zcat *.gz)
```

But it takes more than two hours for creating just one file. There could be a way to improve my code? I think most of the time is spent by `zcat` each file and by the append writing function that seems to be slow. What do you think?

Comment: I’m missing the zcat portion...

Comment: Can you add some data, that would help me understand what you're doing :)

Comment: I still can't figure out what you expect the value of **$p** to be ...

Comment: @JeffSchaller sorry I forgot the command, just edited, it won't work without.

Comment: @tink just added few examples with almost all cases. $p will be the index of the column I need that will be written to a single file named as that column.
I know that it is possibile to process the column without taking file_1.in as input but I've noticed that doing a for loop on more then 2k columns in 24 files takes too much time, so I came up with this solution (not sure if is the best one) as the header of the files is always the same

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I still don't understand the criteria by which you do the sorting of output into files. :} ... can't see any correlation between col2 of file_in.1 and the values that come out of the zips ...

Comment: And I also don't understand what the split operates on if two of three lines don't have the separator : ... all very confusing.

Comment: @tink the file_1.in is just a list (col index, col name) I extracted from the .gz files before processing them just to speed up the process, avoiding to do many times (as the number of .gz files) the same for loop on 2k cols on just that row to extract the col header (wich is always the same).

Comment: @tink I need the split becouse the values on that columns may change as in the very simple file example I provided. Otherwise I'll miss the cols with the ":" separeted values, from wich I need the first value and at the same time I need the values that are in the other format. They aren't just one of three lines, as I said at the beginning the files are 1 to 3 million lines long, with several different cases. I just needed a way to handle those different cases and that one works. Maybe isn't the best solution. If you have in mind any other solution I'll appriciate that.

Comment: So do the index numers in file_1.in repeat, or do you have lines w/ thousands of columns?

Comment: the indexes are just the same as the columns after the FORMAT column in the *.gz files. The columns I need so the files I'll produce are the cols from $10 to $2k and they are fixed

Comment: Sorry for being obtuse ... so, in your sample the data file (not file_1.in) has been deliberately stripped of columns 13-2000?

Comment: yes, they are just very tiny examples I made up

Answer (score 0):

This code does a lot of processing in the loop that is the same between iterations. Awks do not have sophisticated loop optimization to be able to hoist that out of the loop:

```
    for(p in list){
        split($p, sp, ":");
        if (sp[1] != "0|0" && sp[1] != "0" && sp[1] != "."){
```

The `list` associative array does not change after the first file is read to populate it, yet you're repeatedly splitting the index values to test this condition. Instead you could make one pass through the array, and delete the entries which don't match. Or ... not insert those entries into the array in the first place while processing `file_1.in`! Then the splitting and test can be removed: the loop unconditionally visits every entry in `list`.

```
            printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", 
            $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $p) >> out"/"list[p]".tmp"
```

The material being printed here is the same for each iteration of the loop, except for the last `%s` field which takes `$p`. You could use `sprintf` outside of the loop to format the nine fields into a string `str` and then do this:  `printf("%s %s", str, $p) >> out "/" list[p] ".tmp"`.

> Something which is unclear is the following: the `$p` expression in the `printf` assumes that `p` is an integer which is suitable for indexing into fields. So the entire `split` logic looks bogus: it's spltting `p` on the `:` character and then testing certain fields of that split. If `p` is expected to be a positive integer, it shouldn't contain any colons. Might it be that you intended to test the second column here, which is `list[p]`?

Other than that, the program may likely be implicitly slow. It maintains thousands of open file descriptors, through which it adds small amounts of material to numerous output files. Millions of lines are coming in from the compressed files: for each line, the loop iterates over an assoc array containing over two thousand entries, and generates output into that many different files. So millions of compressed lines become billions of uncompressed lines.

You may want to ask yourself what is the purpose of unfolding the data into that representation? If it is for some subsequent processing, maybe a more space-efficient representation could work. The `awk` code looks like it is massively precomputing an association which some kind of database may be able to handle implicitly.